# Format a Vega scatterplot to have percentage axis labels

Tags: javascript, visualization, vega

I have a Vega scatterplot with dynamic data and axis labels. I have no problem with formatting the axes to dollars or rounding to various levels, but I simply cannot get percentages to work, despite using the same d3-format specifiers in other areas of the code (where they work).

This:

```
      {
        name: "XType",
        value: ".0%",
        bind: {
          element: "#xAxisFormat1",
          event: "change",
        },
      },
```

formats as "0.1", "0.2", etc. despite formatting properly in the tooltips as "34%", "35%", etc.

While this:

```
      {
        name: "YType", // changes the data format of the Y-axis
        value: "$,.2s",
        bind: {
          element: "#yAxisFormat1",
          event: "change",
        },
      },
```

formats as I want, as $3.0k" $4.0k" etc.

I am not sure why all of the others are working but the percentage option isn't. I am pulling it directly from the d3 examples documentation.